# Is there any way to compact a String at compile time

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations

I would like to know if there is any way to compact a String at compile time.

Example:
I want to reduce that GraphQL query

```
val q = """
query {
    contacts {
        firstName
        lastName
        phone
    }
}
"""
```

to

```
val q = "query{contacts{firstName,lastName,phone}}"
```

Comment: In Java: `"your string".replaceAll("\\s", "")`.

Comment: @AndyTurner That doesn't work at compile-time, though

Comment: @user depends what you're really looking for. If you mean "I want the entry in the string pool to be the compact one"... I'm not sure there is a way. If you just mean "the only value I want to be able to access via `q` is the compact one", like this.

Comment: @AndyTurner Fair enough. There's an issue to introduce something like `constexpr` to Kotlin - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14652?_ga=2.217967702.132679795.1594393750-474171908.1588704824

Comment: You may be able to use an annotation processor to create a new file containing the compacted query, but it's probably not worth it

Comment: which client library use it at GraphQl

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do macro processing in Kotlin until now, as is said by the someone from JetBrains team [itself](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/compile-time-functions-macros/2097).